# Emulation Station won't load

Tags: emulation, pi-5

Raspberry pi 5.

Official Retropie image have tried both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Emulation Station doesn't load, goes to a picture of a guy on a boat fishing with cormorants.

Multiple tries, please help.

Thank you

Comment: What instructions are you following? The current Retropie image won’t boot on a Pi5 as it’s based on an old OS!